# plenty of strange characters instead of webpage

Tags: wordpress, character, html, display

I have several wordpress blogs hosted on a VPS at OVH (apache - centos 6)
Sometimes, instead of showing the correct web pages, appear some strange signs :
����r�H�(�\2��P�Yw�� �r)e�V�բT�@��.....

But the whole page appears with those signs, not only accented words (I've read many discutions with question marks in black diamonds instead of accented words but obviously the problem i am facing is different)

I have tried Chrome and internet explorer, same issue. 
I have tried on my smartphone, same issue. 
I have tried several of my websites, same issue. 
So the problem doesn't come from the web browser, nor from the PC, nor from the blog.

The problem is erratic. I mean I can load the webpage correctly 3 times in a row, and then the issue comes up the forth time

My httpd.conf does have the line : AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

How to explain this ?
Can this be linked somehow to a too busy server (possible assumption ?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.